# Exponential distribution function.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am having trouble with this question as well. Any help or hints will be really appreciated.

On a TV game show contestants have to complete a particular task. Suppose that the time take for a typical contestant to complete the task is a random variable with an exponential distribution sigma=2, measured in minutes. This means that the probability density is given by.

$$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{x}{2}} & x ≥0\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

a) Calculate the probability that a typical contestant fails to complete the task in 3 minutes.

b) Calculate the probability that a contestant takes over 2 minutes to complete the task given that they do not fail

I keep getting the wrong answers for both of a and b .Any sort of hint for me to understand this better would be really appreciated . 
thanks

Comment: I think you're missing something. "Otherwise" what? Is $x \geq 0$?

Comment: otherwise = 0 , 1/2exp(-x/2) x>=0

Comment: I think there's an extra $y$ there right now. Sorry, not trying to be picky to annoy you.

Comment: thank you for mentioning it so i can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, try integrating that distribution from 3 to $\infty$. This is the probability that the contestant takes 3 minutes or more to complete the task.

For the second question, I'm going to assume that it is considered a failure if the contestant takes more than 3 minutes to complete a task. In this case, integrate the same distribution from 2 to 3 this time.

Does this make sense?